# How to make data column from parent table to be inserted into a column in the child class

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have a parent table called: games. There I have GameID (AI), TournamentID....
Then I have another table called: badminton. There I have GameID, PlayerOneID... where everything can be null (except GameID) and games.GameID is in a relationship with badminton.GameID

Now I am creating games in the Game table with autogenerated GameID but badminton.GameID is always empty. So what I need is:

I create a row in GameID and I want from the column GameID to get that new row and to be inserted in the badminton table.

[this is Game table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UCYL.png)

[This is Badminton table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt9lt.png)

where I should also have new row created with just GameID of 5. I hope I explained my question because I am not really into SQL. I am sorry if its a duplicate question but I have been searching throughout the Internet for more than an hour but I couldn't find a solution that I can implement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your structure right now, mainly that you should probably have a unique ID for your badminton table. With your structure you could consider merging the tables. If you want to move forward with your solution, look into setting up [Triggers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-trigger-student-database/) as they will execute a query when they detect a change in any of your tables. Hope that helps

Comment: I have a question though, if I create the trigger it will be there until I remove it or I always need to mention it in my sql query? Also in this case it would be:

`CREATE TRIGGER CreateGame ON games
AFTER insert
ON badminton
INSERT INTO badminton`? Please correct me where I am wrong

Comment: @RVasilev The trigger will stay there until you get rid of it. The query you showed looks good.